# Uploading images in cloud9ide?

Tags: node.js, ide, cloud9-ide

Anyone else can't upload via the drag and drop function images in clou9ide? The name of the image appears in the file browser in the ide, but the image is broken (displays the broken image icon, in chrome). In fifrefox I get HTTP error [24]:500 not_defined callback is not defined0.1. Ive reported it has a bug to cloud9, but no response and not a lot of other people complaining about this issue. Anyone knows if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drag and drop now works (well on the paid version). It was a un-implemented option at the time.